# Error while running Junit - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to create a framework using selenium WD with cucumber and Junit.
I have set up/ download everything but facing an issue while running it.

I get the following error when I try to execute JUNIT class. Did anyone faced the same issue , and how have you been able o fix it please ?

Versions of Jar files used:

•   Cucumber-core 4.4.0
•   Cucumber-html 4.4.0
•   cobertura code coverage 2.1.1
•   Cucumber-java 4.4.0
•   Cucumber-junit 4.4.0
•   Cucumber-jvm-deps 1.0.6
•   Gherkin 6.0.17
•   Junit 4.12

Error trace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider

Comment: Did u add Gherkins dependency? As far as I know it comes automatically as a part of Cucumber dependency.

Comment: Nope I'm was using cucumber-jvm-deps

Answer (score 0):

This means you are using the wrong combination of jars. (Afaik Cucumber-jvm v4 does not use Gherkin 6.)

Note that Cucumber recommends using a **package manager (Maven or Gradle)** to prevent this problem and make sure you get the right transitive dependencies.

Check the installation instructions in the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/) to see which dependencies you need.

For Maven:

```
If you are going to use the lambda expressions API (Java 8) to write the step definitions, 
add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Otherwise, to write them using annotated methods, 
add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```